# When was support for AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_AUTOCONVERTPCM added to WASAPI?

Tags: c++, windows, audio, wasapi

Does anyone know when support for the AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_AUTOCONVERTPCM stream flag was added to WASAPI? MSDN mentions this flag briefly, but doesn't go into much detail regarding its use and which versions of Windows support this.

I'm using the Platform SDK that comes with Visual Studio 2015 and AUDCLNT_STREAMFLAGS_AUTOCONVERTPCM isn't even defined.

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the separate Windows 10 SDK, even though most of the components are installed with VS2015:

https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk

I had the same problem as you, and installing the latest Windows 10 SDK solved it for me. (Version 10.0.14393.795 at the time of writing.)